# PHP: How to check whether the URL is Youtube's or vimeo's

Tags: php, url, youtube, vimeo

How can I write a function to check whether the provided URLs is youtube or vimeo?

For instance, I have this two URLs that I store in a database as strings,

```
http://vimeo.com/24456787

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj18UQjPpGA&feature=player_embedded
```

If the URL is youtube then I will rewrite the URL to,

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/rj18UQjPpGA?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
```

If the URL is vimeo then I will rewrite this URL to,

```
http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=24456787
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you receiving it in the first place, and checking whether it's valid?

Comment: I do not like none of the answers posted here, I'd prefer a method pinging the url and analyzing the response, I guess if it can be done this way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### As others have noted in the comments, **this is a quick and dirty solution** that does not handle edge cases well. If the url contains "youtube"(example.com/youtube) it will return a false positive. The `parse_url()` solution [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619027/107768) is a much more robust solution.

[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) work well for this type of thing, but often `strpos` or `substr` are faster performance wise. Check out the PHP documentation for [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Below the examples there is a note for exactly this thing.

Here is prototype code:

```
function videoType($url) {
    if (strpos($url, 'youtube') > 0) {
        return 'youtube';
    } elseif (strpos($url, 'vimeo') > 0) {
        return 'vimeo';
    } else {
        return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

Obviously returning a string isn't the best idea, but you get the point. Substitute your own business logic.

Comment: Why is this answer better than parse_url answer?

Comment: @Icode4food - does strpos work for any case of the characters?  i.e. "youtube = YOUTUBE" ?

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It fails to return "unknown" for URLs that contain "youtube" or "vimeo" in other parts of the URL. E.g. "http://foo.com/youtube/123"

Comment: It won't detect short urls

Comment: Wrong answer. Try to put the below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969062/regex-to-find-youtube-link-in-string. This will find as a youtube link but it is not

Comment: Adding a dot youtube. or vimeo. to be sur that is't not in a url path.like mywebsite.com/youtube/my-youtube-videos.html

Answer (score 32):

Use the `parse_url` function to split the URL up and then just do your normal checks

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj18UQjPpGA&feature=player_embedded';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
```

Will give you this array

```
array
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'www.youtube.com' (length=15)
  'path' => string '/watch' (length=6)
  'query' => string 'v=rj18UQjPpGA&feature=player_embedded' (length=37)
```

Comment: Checking for the substring on the host part is the best solution.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf There are three options: `www.youtube.com`, `youtube.com` and `youtu.be`. So just check them with **or** `||`

Answer (score 21):

I recently wrote this function to do exactly this, hopefully it's useful to someone:

```
    /**
 * [determineVideoUrlType used to determine what kind of url is being submitted here]
 * @param  string $url either a YouTube or Vimeo URL string
 * @return array will return either "youtube","vimeo" or "none" and also the video id from the url
 */

public function determineVideoUrlType($url) {


    $yt_rx = '/^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/';
    $has_match_youtube = preg_match($yt_rx, $url, $yt_matches);


    $vm_rx = '/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([‌​0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/';
    $has_match_vimeo = preg_match($vm_rx, $url, $vm_matches);


    //Then we want the video id which is:
    if($has_match_youtube) {
        $video_id = $yt_matches[5]; 
        $type = 'youtube';
    }
    elseif($has_match_vimeo) {
        $video_id = $vm_matches[5];
        $type = 'vimeo';
    }
    else {
        $video_id = 0;
        $type = 'none';
    }


    $data['video_id'] = $video_id;
    $data['video_type'] = $type;

    return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_match()`:

```
$u1="http://vimeo.com/24456787";
$u2="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj18UQjPpGA&feature=player_embedded";

if(preg_match('/http:\/\/(www\.)*vimeo\.com\/.*/',$u1)){
    // do vimeo stuff
    echo "Vimeo URL found!\n";
}

if(preg_match('/http:\/\/(www\.)*youtube\.com\/.*/',$u2)){
    // do youtube stuff
    echo "YouTube URL found!\n";
}
```

Comment: Why oh why would you willingly pick `/` as the delimiter when your pattern is a URL fragment?

Answer (score 3):

Since all you want to do is check for the presence of a string, use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). If it doesn't have youtube.com or vimeo.com in it, the url is malformed, right? stripos is case insensitive, too.

```
if(stripos($url,'youtu')===false){
    //must be vimeo
    } else {
    //is youtube
    }
```

Comment: Does not handle short urls like youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

You can try my solution:

```
function checkServer( $domains=array(), $url ) {
    foreach ( $domains as $domain ) {
        if ( strpos($url, $domain ) > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
if( checkServer(array("youtube.com","youtu.be"), $url ) ) {
    //is Youtube url
}
elseif( checkServer(array("vimeo.com"), $url ) ) {
    //is Vimeo
}
elseif ( checkServer(array("any domain"), $url ) ) {
    //is Any Domain
}else {
    //unknow domain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). What language are you using?

Edit: noticed your tag was php. It would be something like this:

```
<?php
// get host name from URL
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',
    "http://www.youtube.com/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[1];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo {$matches[0]}\n"; //youtube.com
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<?php
  if (strpos($videourl, 'youtube') > 0) {
    echo 'This is a youtube video';
  } 
?>
```

Comment: That sounds pretty wrong. What if `$videourl` contains this anywhere else? Like `this-is-not-youtube.com`

Comment: It will work in this case as well. Because it will check the position of "youtube" in the whole string and if it found the word youtube in the string then it will return the position of that string and will return the true result. in your example the position of the youtube word is 12 i.e. greater than 0. So, it will echo that message (This is a youtube video). You can do the same for vimeo as well.

Comment: But the URL `this-is-not-youtube.com` should not return "This is a youtube video", should it?

Comment: Yes, in that case parse_url function can be used to get the hostname to match it exactly.