# blog that using posts like links or youtube links

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have created a blog in php. Users can post anything like a text, or a link, or youtube link. I use preg_replace() in order my code to determine when there is link or a youtube link. This is what I use:

```
<?php

//...code


$row['comment'] = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $row['comment']);


$row['comment'] = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i"," <object width=\"100px;\" height=\"100px;\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/$1&hl=en&fs=1\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/$1&hl=en&fs=1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"400px;\" height=\"200px;\"></embed></object>",$row['comment']);

  // then prints the $row['comment']

 ?>
```

my preg_replace() works fine and determines with success when there is link or a youtube link. The only problem is that when there is youtube link posted, It is displayed 2 times...probably because I gave for  $row['comment'] 2 different declarations. Any idea how can I get rid of this? Is it better to combine the above 2 statements in 1? and how can I do this? Or any other "if" statement that I can use?

**Any idea how to combine the above 2 statements in one?**

Comment: Check first if it's a youtube link if it's not check for a link

Comment: any idea how to write this?

Comment: your youtube regex should EXCLUDE links that are already "linkified".

Comment: looks good any idea how to do this my code?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the strpos function for checking a string (in your case url). See the [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/strpos) documentation for more details.

Using an if structure is recommended because you need to do different implementation for every link type. The following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618967/php-how-to-check-whether-the-url-is-youtubes-or-vimeos) is very useful.

Comment: got any idea how can I modify my code using this function?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick.

```
function get_link_type($url)
{
    if(strpos($url, 'youtube') > 0)
    {
        return 'youtube';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'default';
    }
}

$url = 'http://www.google.com/watch?v=rj18UQjPpGA&feature=player_embedded';
$link_type = get_link_type($url);

if($link_type == 'youtube')
{
    $new_link = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//'. $url .'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
else
{
    $new_link = '<a href="'. $url .'">'. $url .'</a>';
}

echo $new_link;
```