# Regex to find Youtube Link in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string like that:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard  dummy text ever since the 1500s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
```

This is what I have:

```
preg_match("(?:http://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)/(?:watch\?)?([^\s]+?)", $content, $m);
    var_dump( $m );
```

and want to extract the youtube link form it.
The video id, would be okay, too.

Nay help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would work for you,

```
\S*\bwww\.youtube\.com\S*
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters.

Code would be,

```
preg_match('~\S*\bwww\.youtube\.com\S*~', $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vJ0nU7/1)

And i made Some corrections to your original regex.

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\s]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vJ0nU7/3)

```
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard  dummy text ever since the 1500s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type";
preg_match('~(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\s]+)~', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM
    [1] => 7TL02DA5MZM
)
```

Comment: I am getting errors with your regex:Unknown modifier '?' in

Comment: see my update.. It works for me. I think you forget to add the delimiters.

Comment: It ignores youtu.be (ex.https://youtu.be/NFD1dtTosQc)

Comment: see my update.. Just put `v=` to the previous optional group.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the forward slash characters!

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\S+?v=\K\S+
```

You can get video id by matching youtube url and then discarding using `\K`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/21

```
$re = "/(?:https?:\\/\\/)?www\\.youtube\\.com\\S+?v=\\K\\S+/i";
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: almost okay. What about youtu.be?

Comment: @user998163 (?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be) use this in place YouTube\.com

Comment: can you update your replay, please? I tried (?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)  but did not succeed.

Comment: @user998163 https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/22

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following regexp:

```
https?:\/\/(w{3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?.+?(\s|$)
```

Here is how I am using this:

```
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard  dummy text ever since the 1500s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type";

preg_match("/https?:\/\/(w{3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?.+?(\s|$)/", $str, $matches);

$ytube = $matches[0];
$parse = parse_url($ytube);
parse_str($parse["query"], $query);

echo $ytube;
print_r($parse);
print_r($query);
```

And here is the output of the items:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TL02DA5MZM
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => www.youtube.com
    [path] => /watch
    [query] => v=7TL02DA5MZM 
)
Array
(
    [v] => 7TL02DA5MZM 
)
```